# MySql: join from other table and count results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I hope the title is not too confusing - I have no idea how to call this.

Imagine you have a table of products:

```
+----+---------------------------+-------+
| id | name                      | stock |
+----+---------------------------+-------+
|  1 | 1. Product of set         |     2 |
|  2 | 2. Product of set         |     5 |
|  3 | 3. Product of set         |     3 |
|  4 | Set of Product 1, 2 and 3 |     0 |
+----+---------------------------+-------+
```

Products 1-3 can be sold allone, but they can also be sold as a set (which is product 4). So we have another table:

```
+---------+-------------+-------+
| product | set_product | count |
+---------+-------------+-------+
|       1 |           4 |     1 |
|       2 |           4 |     2 |
|       3 |           4 |     1 |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

... which states that product 4 consists of 1x product 1, 2x product 2 and 1x product 3.

In the products-table there is a column "stock" which indicates how many of each product is currently in stock.

**The Q is: How can I get the stock of product 4 (which of course depends on the stocks of product 1-3) with one SELECT?**

---

To setup the testcase, I created this code:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, unique key(id),
    `name` TINYTEXT,
    `stock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 
);

CREATE TABLE sets (
    `product` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `set_product` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `count` int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products SET id=1, name="1. Product of set", stock=2;
INSERT INTO products SET id=2, name="2. Product of set", stock=5;
INSERT INTO products SET id=3, name="3. Product of set", stock=3;
INSERT INTO products SET id=4, name="Set of Product 1, 2 and 3";

INSERT INTO sets SET product=1, set_product=4, count=1;
INSERT INTO sets SET product=2, set_product=4, count=2;
INSERT INTO sets SET product=3, set_product=4, count=1;
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the sample data you posted?

Comment: I've add answer with all product with calculated counts

Comment: @RomanPekar, OP says for product 4.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select p.name, ifnull(min(ps.stock / s.count), p.stock) as stock
from products as p
    left outer join sets as s on s.set_product = p.id
    left outer join products as ps on ps.id = s.product
group by p.name
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3be64/26)

you also can do union solution

```
select p.id, p.name, min(ps.stock / s.count) as stock
from products as p
    inner join sets as s on s.set_product = p.id
    inner join products as ps on ps.id = s.product
group by p.id, p.name

union all

select p.id, p.name, p.stock
from products as p
where p.id not in (select distinct tt.set_product from sets as tt)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3be64/32)

Comment: why? If you have 2 of product1, 5 of product2 and 3 of product 3, you can try to combine product 4 by dividing stock of each product on count of this product in set and then getting minimum - so you can get 2 of product 4 from this stock

Comment: @danihp i doubt OP have only 4 products in DB, so I gave more general answer. My answer is ready to work with any numbers of products, and in the second part you can see two queries combined, one for simple products and one fo set products.

Answer (score 0):

You sould take the min stock for all set products. Nut you should take in mind that the numer of items for this product in set:

```
 select 
       coalesce( min( p.stock / s.`count`), 0)
       as stock_product
 from 
   products p 
 left outer join
   sets s on
      p.id = s.product
 where
   set_product = 4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3be64/19/0

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this... (it's MS SQL, but it shouldn't be too far from the truth..)

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.set_product
              , ISNULL(MIN((p.stock/s.count)),0) calculated_stock
FROM [sets] s
INNER JOIN products p
  ON p.id = s.product
GROUP BY s.set_product;
```

Comment: This will display all sets you have with the minimal stock for all (lowest available value of all set parts, divided by the times the product is used in the set).